# Is there a way to minimize the standard deviation in linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Here is the scenario:

There are *n* boxes with $C_{a}$ of capacity at the beginning of each box before assigning.

I want to fit *x* parcels into the boxes, letting the capacity left for each boxes are as even as possible.

The solution I have thought of is:
$$
 Minimize(\sum_{a=1}^{n}(C_{a}-D_{a})^2)
$$
where $D_{a}$ represents the amount of parcels assigned to $Box_{n}$

Is there a way to turn this into a linear problem?

Comment: If you use the 1-norm or the inf-norm instead of the 2-norm, you can reformulate your problem into a linear problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by 1-norm and inf-norm?

Comment: I meant $\min(\sum_{a=1}^n |C_a - D_a|)$ (1-norm) or $\min(\max_{a=1}^n |C_a - D_a|)$ (inf-norm).
See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm

Comment: min($|C_{a}-D_{a}|$) will be the same if Box 1 with 5 capacities got assigned 1 parcel, and Box 2 with 3 capacities got assigned 2 parcels, and if Box 1 got assigned 4 parcels, and Box 2 got assigned 0 parcel. Both of the outcome of the objective function will be 4

Comment: Yes, it does not penalize large deviations from the capacities as much as the 2-norm in your original message. Using the 2-norm results in a Quadratic Problem.

Comment: If the capacities and parcel sizes are all integers, it is possible to linearize the objective using a gaggle of binary variables. That does not necessarily mean it is desirable, since most decent MIP solvers can handle minimizing a convex quadratic objective function.